# Angular - Property 'options' does not exist on type 'HTMLOptionElement'

Tags: angular, typescript, html-select

I am trying to change the options in a dropdown based on the value chosen from a different dropdown. Got this from the website: [Form Select Change Dynamic List Option Elements Tutorial](http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Form-Select-Change-Dynamic-List-Option-Elements-Tutorial). However, I am getting the error ***Property 'options' does not exist on type 'HTMLOptionElement'*** as the tutorial is done on Javascript. The code is shown below:

```
changeWidget() {
    var roles = document.getElementById("roles") as HTMLOptionElement;
    var widgets = document.getElementById("widgets") as HTMLOptionElement;
    widgets.innerHTML = "";

    if (roles.value == "Startups") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "products|Products", "people|People", "matching|Matching"];

    }
    for (var option in optionArray) {
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        widgets.options.add(newOption); 
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is the correct typecast that I need for this. Is it HTMLElement, HTMLSelectElement, HTMLInputElement, etc.?

Comment: can you create a sandbox for the same

Comment: it should be `HTMLSelectElement`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), and use the `add()` method to add options.

```
changeWidget() {
    var roles = document.getElementById("roles") as HTMLSelectElement;
    var widgets = document.getElementById("widgets") as HTMLSelectElement;
    widgets.innerHTML = "";

    if (roles.value == "Startups") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "products|Products", "people|People", "matching|Matching"];

    }
    for (var option in optionArray) {
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        widgets.add(newOption); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to add option widget should be HTMLSelectElement and selected item to be HTMLOptionElement

```
changeWidget() {
    var roles = document.getElementById("roles") as HTMLOptionElement;
    var widgets = document.getElementById("widgets") as HTMLSelectElement;
    widgets.innerHTML = "";

    if (roles.value == "Startups") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "products|Products", "people|People", "matching|Matching"];

    }
    for (var option in optionArray) {
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        widgets.options.add(newOption); 
    }
}
```